# Polynomial derivative in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

How do I calculate the first order derivative of a polynomial in NumPy?

I expect, that the derivative of `x^2 + 2x + 14` will be `0 + 2x + 2` (or `2x + 2` for short).

Using the linear algebra notation, the operation of taking a derivative from [14, 2, 1] vector in P(F) would produce [2, 2, 0] vector in P(F).

For some reason, NumPy and `polynomial.polyder` results in [0] in P(F), neither respecting the dimension nor the properties of the mentioned linear operator.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyder` takes an arraylike of coefficients, not a `numpy.polynomial.Polynomial` instance. To differentiate a `numpy.polynomial.Polynomial`, use its `deriv` method:

```
derivative = p.deriv()
```